# Draw controlled-SWAP gate using Qcircuit

Tags: circuits, qcircuit

I want to draw this circuit using Qcircuit package:

[image]

This was my attempt:

```
\Qcircuit @C=0.5cm @R=.5cm {
\qw  & \qw &\ctrl{1} & \qw & \qw\\
\lstick{\psi_1} & \qw & \link{1}{-1} & \rstick{\psi_2} \qw \\
\lstick{\psi_2} & \qw & \link{-1}{-1} & \rstick{\psi_1} \qw}
```

but I got this result:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: how did you define `\link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a copy of LaTeX with Qcircuit handy right now, but the following should do it:

```
\Qcircuit @C=0.25cm @R=.25cm {
& \qw & \ctrl{2} & \qw & \qw\\
\lstick{\psi_1} & \qw \link{1}{1} & & \link{1}{-1} & \rstick{\psi_2} \qw \\
& & \\
\lstick{\psi_2} & \qw \link{-1}{1} & & \link{-1}{-1} & \rstick{\psi_1} \qw}
```

I added another row and column so that the control has something to land on in the center of the swap.  You might have to fiddle with it a bit to get the spacing you want.  I often use \push on a rule with width=0 for this sort of thing.

Comment: request definition of link

Comment: \link is defined as follows in Qcircuit.tex:

\newcommand{\link}[2]{\ar @{-} [#1,#2]}
    % Draws a wire or connecting line to the element #1 rows down and #2 columns forward.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :)